# Connection refused exception while getting details using Rest

Tags: java, rest, spring-rest

I am using rest services to get information by passing a request.Sometimes i see this information in logs.

```
2018-02-01 12:40:15,136 DEBUG app.security.org.Monitor restFailure. url: http://localhost:80/my/api/getDetails

org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: Connection to http://localhost:80 refused; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:80 refused
```

So my question here is..When will the above exception occur?

When the connections to localhost are not accepting or even when we have network issues from client side?

And how can we get the status code for the call?

Comment: `Connection refused` means the port is not opened or the server has reached it's capacity. Explore ResourceAccessException class to see what it offers.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz tahnks. Any idea what would be the HTTP status code in this case? I know it will be in 500's but not sure what exactly it will be.

Comment: There's no HTTP status code since those are returned by server but none was reached in this case.